# Unable to figure out the SyntaxError in Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework and i have the below code to identifyuser for enabling push notification.

```
$scope.identifyUser=function(){
    console.log("Ionic User :  Identifying Ionic User");
    var user = $ionicUser.get();

    if(!user.user_id){
        user.user_id = $ionicUser.generateGUID();
    }

    angular.extend(user, {
        name:"Poornima"
    });

    $ionicUser.identify(user).then(funtion(){
        alert("User id is : "+ user.user_id);
    });

    $scope.openRouter();
}
```

I am getting the below error when the controller is loaded

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

[image: Chrome_developer_Tool_Console_Image]

Not sure what i am missing. please help.

Comment: You typed `funtion` instead of `function`. The `c` is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple misspelling: `funtion` should be `function`

Answer (score 0):

You got a typo:

```
$ionicUser.identify(user).then(funtion(){
    alert("User id is : "+ user.user_id);
});
```

`funtion` -> `function`